# Jenkins shell script add Unix user to group

Tags: bash, shell, unix, docker, jenkins

I am running two consecutive shell scripts in a Jenkinsfile:

```
stage('running scripts') {
    sh "sudo script1.sh"
    sh "groups && whoami"
}
```

*script1.sh*:

```
groupadd docker
usermod -aG docker ubuntu
groups ubuntu
```

Console output is:

```
ubuntu : ubuntu adm dialout cdrom floppy sudo audio dip video plugdev netdev lxd docker
```

But second shell script (i.e: `sh "groups && whoami"`) shows that ubuntu user is NOT in docker group:

```
+ groups
ubuntu adm dialout cdrom floppy sudo audio dip video plugdev netdev lxd
+ whoami
ubuntu
```

What am I doing wrong ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group permissions apply on login, and jenkins doesn't rerun the login between steps of the pipeline. I'd recommend adding the group to your build slave (or docker image for your build slave).

Comment: Thanks, great solution !